# Put widget on desktop automatically after installation

Tags: android, android-widget, android-manifest

I have developed some widget and what I want to attain is to put it on desktop automatically after installation without doing it manually.

Thanks in advance,
kogut

Comment: I thought about some service which could periodical check whether that widget is on desktop and if it is not service would put it on desktop. I am not sure if it good approach.

Comment: Even if it were possible, the problem is that you can't automatically start your application at installation time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can not do that.